Serial communication, how to set DCB correctly?
I've been fiddling with serial communication for a while now with a cheap copy of an Arduino Nano.
The thing is, it has never worked well, and I was never sur that my configuration is correct.
I open the port with GENERIC_WRITE, GENERIC_READ, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED and I appropriately call SetCommMask with the EV_RXCHAR flag.
I call SetCommState with the following code, the commented part is from when I was trying to completely set the DCB. I have tried to :

Briefly connect the board to the Arduino IDE
Use a program I made, that would call GetCommState hopping it would get the configuration that the Arduino IDE had set. It doesn't seem to work and now my program (another one that reads/write) doesn't work at all anymore.

    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    if (!GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams)) {
        printf("Error getting device state\n");
        CloseHandle(hComm);
    }

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = 9600;                              ///< Current baud 
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;                                     ///< Number of bits/byte, 4-8 
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;                                ///< 0-4 = no, odd, even, mark, space 
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;                            ///< 0, 1, 2 = 1, 1.5, 2 
    dcbSerialParams.fTXContinueOnXoff = 1;
    dcbSerialParams.fOutX = 0;
    dcbSerialParams.fInX = 0;

    if (!SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams)) {
        printf("Error setting device parameters\n");
        CloseHandle(hComm);
    }

    GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);
    printf("%hd %hd\n", dcbSerialParams.XonLim, dcbSerialParams.XoffLim);

I'm pretty sure I'll be able to fix it by looking into the CH340 datasheet.
My question is, how do I get the whole correct setting for the Arduino ?
Also, if the Arduino IDE and putty manage to work with the Arduino correctly, it must mean that the driver is working correctly right ?
EDIT : Here is the code for the setup on the Arduino
void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


I saw a very similar or identical question to this yesterday, how is this new one different from that one?

Please add a few more details about what "it has never worked well," might mean. In what way did it not work as expected? Did you lose characters? Did you get wrong speed? What else?

Since the Arduino IDE managed to connect to the Nano clone, did you manage to load a sketch onto it that uses the serial port? Can you show the Serial.begin(…); code?

Since the only UART signals connected to the microcontroller are TX and RX, you should explicitly disable anything to do with the RTS, CTS, DCD, DSR, and DTR flow control: dcbSerialParams.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE; dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = FALSE; dcbSerialParams.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE; dcbSerialParams.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE; dcbSerialParams.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE;

This was the sort of scenario where sysInternals' portmon was hugely useful, to see what was different between successful and unsuccessful communication.  Unfortunately it only supports quite old OS versions.

These articles may be helpful. Windows COM Communication via CDC COM Port to Arduino, Communication Arduino-C++ do not read Arduino

In my previous comment, the value of dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = FALSE; should have been dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE; but it is the same numeric value 0. Setting dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE; would also be fine. The only difference is that the RTS line would be constantly asserted instead of constantly de-asserted, but it does not matter since the signal is not wired up anyway. Similarly dcbSerialParams.fDtrControl can be set to DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE or DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE.

@ThomasJager I didn't find the question you are refeering to.
@IanAbbott I added the Serial.begin

Actually what I did is, I connected the Arduino IDE to the comm port for an instant. Then I launched a program that calls GetCommState and diplayed all of the fields and set them the same way in my original programs and now it works.
